# chunk(int) is deprecated and marked for removal

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am quite new to Spring Batch. I have created some code using "chunk" but it is deprecated so I should remove it. I have tried to change it many ways but it does not work. I can't seem to find a way to modify my code without this chunk element. The error is on the following line:    .<Person, Person>chunk(3).

```
    package batchprocessing;


@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    private final JobRepository jobRepository;
    private final PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    public BatchConfiguration(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager 
transactionManager) {
        this.jobRepository = jobRepository;
        this.transactionManager = transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader() {
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Person>()
                .name("personItemReader")
                .resource(new ClassPathResource("sample-data.csv"))
                .delimited()
                .names("prhoin", "nrhoin")
                .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>() {{
                    setTargetType(Person.class);
                }})
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ValidatingItemProcessor<Person> processor() {
        ValidatingItemProcessor<Person> validatingItemProcessor = new ValidatingItemProcessor<>();
        validatingItemProcessor.setValidator(new SpringValidator<>());
        return validatingItemProcessor;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Person> writer(DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        return items -> {
            for (Person item : items) {
                jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO people (prhoin, nrhoin) VALUES (?, ?)",
                        item.prhoin, item.nrhoin);
            }
        };
   }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return new StepBuilder("step1", jobRepository)
                .<Person, Person>chunk(3)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer(null)) // Pass a null DataSource for now, it will be injected by 
Spring later
                .transactionManager(transactionManager)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job runJob() {
        return new JobBuilder("importUserJob", jobRepository)
                    .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                    .start(step1())
                    .build();
        }

    @Bean
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("your.driver.class");
        dataSource.setUrl("your.jdbc.url");
        dataSource.setUsername("your.username");
        dataSource.setPassword("your.password");
        return dataSource;
    }

    public static class Person {
        private String prhoin;
        private String nrhoin;

    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the [API docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/step/builder/StepBuilder.html#chunk(int)) for the deprecation notice, you'll see it says the following:

> **Deprecated, for removal: This API element is subject to removal in a future version.**
> *use [`chunk(int, PlatformTransactionManager)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/step/builder/StepBuilder.html#chunk(int,org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager))*

So essentially, you need to add the `transactionManager` that you autowired into your configuration as the second argument of the `chunk()` method:

```java
return new StepBuilder("step1", jobRepository)
    .<Person, Person>chunk(3, transactionManager) // Add this
    .reader(reader())
    .processor(processor())
    .writer(writer(null))
    .transactionManager(transactionManager) // You can remove this
    .build();
```

You can also remove the `.transactionManager(transactionManager)` line because that's now implied by using the `.chunk()` builder method.

This change was made because chunking requires a transactionmanager, and the new API makes it obvious.